# Hacer el symbolic link de laravel en un servidor compartido (cpanel)

Tags: laravel, cpanel

alguien me podria apoyar en como se haria el symbolic link de laravel en un hosting compartido, ya que para mostrar los archivos tengo ocupando la calse Storage, si podrian apoyarme.

Comment: Si por tu tipo de cuenta, cpanel no tiene la opción, deberás contactarte con el equipo de soporte del hosting y pedirles que lo hagan por ti.

Answer (score 2):

El link simbólico **SI** lo puedes crear fácilmente aunque el servidor sea compartido, probablemente no tengas acceso ssh pero si puedes ejecutar el comando utilizando la clase Artisan de la siguiente forma:

Importas la clase al principio de la clase en donde lo usarás:

```
use Artisan;
```

Y ya en alguna parte de algún método de tu clase ejecutas:

```
public function crearStorage(){
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
}
```

También podrías ejecutarlo dentro del archivo `routes.php` sin necesidad de importar la clase:

```
Route::get('/storage-link', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Y listo, ya tendrás tu link simbólico en `public/storage`

Comment: Excelente aporte. También tuve ese problema con los enlaces simbólicos, los shared hostings limitan mucho. Pero con estas pocas lineas lo conseguí

Answer (score 1):

Esto generalmente **NO** es posible en la mayoría de servidores compartidos, sin embargo tienes dos opciones para intentar ejecutar el comando y verificar si funciona:

- Crear un cron job que ejecute el comando (solo es necesario ejecutarlo una vez), y revisar la salida de este.
- Revisar las capacidades que tenga la línea de comando (si es que el hosting ofrece acceso por línea de comando/SSH) e intentar ejecutar el comando, tal vez funcione.

Una solución sencilla para esto es crear un «disco» en la configuración de Laravel , que apunte a un directorio dentro de public.

Answer (score 0):

para crear el symbolic link en un servidor con cPanel, cree una ruta con este contenido:

```
Route::get('/storage-link', function(){
    $targetFolder = storage_path('app/public');
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
    echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
});
```

Luego la ejecuto desde el sitio https://tu.sitio.com/storage-link

Debe salir el mensaje **Symlink process successfully completed**  con eso queda habilitado